# How would I track and display a number of questions and answer shown to the user?

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner in Swift programming and just started learning this new language.

How would I track and display a number of questions and answer shown to the user (two separate values) for a quiz app?

Here's my code below:

```
@IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var answerLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var countingQuestionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var countingAnswerLabel: UILabel!

let questions: [String] = [
    "What is 5+2?",
    "What does TCP stand for?",
    "How many wheels does a car have?"
]
let answers: [String] = [
    "7",
    "Transfer Control Protocol",
    "Four"
]

var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0
var currentQuestionCount: Int = 0
//var currentAnwserCount: Int = 0

@IBAction func showNewQuestion(_: UIButton) {
    currentQuestionIndex += 1
    if currentQuestionIndex == questions.count {
        currentQuestionIndex = 0
    }

    let question: String = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    questionLabel.text = question
    answerLabel.text = "???"
}

@IBAction func showAnswer(_: UIButton) {
    let answer: String = answers[currentQuestionIndex]
    answerLabel.text = answer
}
```

Comment: This question is pretty broad. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Well i needed to understand how to track and display a number of question and answer shown to a user in the quiz app. I understand the logic but coding is my issue so i know i would need a counter? Correct? And then print out the number of question and answer shown, but how would it be coded in swift. If you where making a quiz app how would you code it?